# Multiple redirects

Tags: http, redirect, seo, http-redirect

Is there any SEO implications or other issues with the following redirect scenario?

```
301 HTTP  /contactus/
302 HTTP  /Conact_us_forms/Contact_us/
200 HTTPS /Conact_us_forms/Contact_us/
```

BTW, the scenario is a result of legacy systems which are soon to be replaced. Sound familar ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple of issues with the redirects above. The more the number of redirects, search engines will have trouble following final urls and crawl them and affect the time spent in subsequent calls.
1. Google does not like too many redirects.
2. /contactus/ is doing 301(permamnent redirect) to /Conact_us_forms/Contact_us/ which in turn is doing 302 (temporary redirect). SO search engines will remember "/Conact_us_forms/Contact_us/" which will always do a 302, which is bad instead of indexing the final url.

The correct solution to this to avoid all redirect, else reduce the number of hops and trying to do 301 as much as possible, so that search engines will try to remember the final URL.Hope this helps.